# assistance with slots program in java

Tags: java, slots

```
public class slots 
{

public static void main(String[]args)
{

    public  String pull() {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);
        if(rand == 1)
            return "cherries";
        else if(rand == 2)
            return "bar";
        else
            return "7";
    }
    string1 = pull();
    string2 = pull();
    string3 = pull();
}
}
class TripleString 
{
    public static final int MAX_LEN = 20;
    private String string1;
    private String string2;
    private String string3;

    TripleString()
    {
        string1 ="";
        string2 ="";
        string3 ="";
    }

    public void setTripleString (String str1, String str2, String str3) 
    {
        string1 = str1;
        string2 = str2;
        string3 = str3;
    }

    public String getstring1()
    {
        return string1;
    }

    public String getstring2()
    {
        return string2;
    }

    public String getstring3()
    {
        return string3;
    }

    private boolean vaildString( String str ) 
    {
        if (str.length() >0 && str.length() <= MAX_LEN) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have this code and am trying to create a slot machine that will randomly return these values but there is a syntax error on string pull() that im not sure how to fix. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Why is `pull` declared within `main`?

Comment: You should tell us what the error is.

Comment: What kind of "syntax error" are you getting?

Comment: If you're not using an IDE, you might want to consider switching to using one as it will point out errors like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't define another method inside of the `main` method; move `pull` out of `main`. Also, it looks like you meant to make `pull` a `static` method (since you will be calling it in a `static` context within `main`). Lastly, don't forget to declare the types of your variables in `main`, so you would want `String string1 = pull()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `string1`, `string2` and `string3` in your `main` method that's inside of your `slots` class, when you declare these variables in your `TripleStrings` class.

You should also (by convention) use `Slots` instead of `slots` as your class name. Every Java type should begin with an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
public class slots 
{

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    String string1 = pull();
    String string2 = pull();
    String string3 = pull();
  }

  public static String pull() {
    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);
    if(rand == 1)
      return "cherries";
    else if(rand == 2)
      return "bar";
    else
      return "7";
    }
  }
```

...